# there is "flickering" in my short animation

Tags: rendering, animation

so here is the video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_ZOoBg1XBId-OWaVMTW0I0_e0kgNNW6T/view?usp=sharing
there is some kind of a problem with the render, the ground floor until the 8th second, there is kind of a flickering (i dont know what to call that).
i used sheepit to render.
anyone know what might be the reason and how to fix it?

Comment: Please in the future don't make people download the video if possible.

Comment: how else can i show the problem?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lMo2JeiQJAWL6sH_eApmjyHd_jS68qwm Here is a google drive link

Comment: there it is, but now the flickering is not so visible because on google the quality is low, so do  u know what might be the reason?

Comment: It would help if you could share some more info, like the render settings. Did you try to render some frames yourself maybe limited to only the floor (making it faster and limiting it), to test if it appears there too?